# Can not print data from API request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I am trying to learn working with API calls and responses and I needed a basic value that comes from api response but I wasn't able to get it work. So here is my problem;

```
(function worker() {
$.get('URL', function(data) {
   $('#numbers').html(data); });
})();
```

I use this code and this works perfectly fine, and writes the API response to my HTML page. Also the API calls return the value in this format;

```
{
"success":"true",
"field1": {"number1":"number1_val","number2":"number2_val"},
"field2": {"number11":"number11_val","number22":"number22_val"}
}
```

Now, I tried to write the values from API response and I was successfull for writing the "success" value like this;

```
$('#success_val').html(data.success);
```

It printed `true` value to my HTML website in given `#success_val` field. However, when I tried to write the field1, or the first value of field1, I wasn't successful. I tried

```
$('#numbers').html(data.field1); => No success, empty page
$('nu#mbers').html(data.field1[0]); => No success, empty page
```

So, at this point, what I need to store & use is the "number11" value from field 2. I have read and searched for over an hour and found out that this api return is not a valid "array" return, instead it is called "field" (I might be wrong), but I couldn't find any info about how can I get the "number11" data from this api response.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#numbers').html(data.field1); => No success, empty page`

Does `data.field1` exist for sure? or spelling check.

you can get keys by `Object.keys(data)`.

If exist data, it return `["success", "filed2", "field2"]`.
In the same way, you already know key, like `number11`, 
`data.field2.number11` or `data["field2"]["number11"]` return value.
If you don't know key, `data["filed2"][Object.keys(data)[0]]` return value

Comment: Weirdly, when I try alerting the "data.field1", it alerts the datas from field1 such as "number1:number1_val","number2:number2_val". But can't get them printed on webpage

Comment: I have tried object.keys(data) and it returns three parameters `success,field1,field2`.

Also if I try running the object.keys as (data.field2), it returns `number11,number22`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10366589/sh-k I have solved the problem in given way;

As I wasn't able to print output from field2 to HTML, I have checked keys at field2 with this code;

```
alert(Object.keys(data.field2));
```

and it returned

```
number11,number22
```

since I only needed number11 from that API response, I did the following;

```
var.storednumber = Object.keys(data.field2);
var.storednumber = storednumber[0];
$('#numbers').html(storednumber);
```

and I was able to get the number I wanted printed on the screen without any problem :)

There could be a better solution or fix for the issue I am having, but for now, this has solved. I guess the problem lies on the API response type as it doesn't return an array formatted data.